# How to use bootstrap in Angular 2 with vanilla js/es6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2

I'm trying to implement an Angular 2 app without TypeScript and I'm stuck in how to bootstrap it (can find any example).

My app (without the bootstrap()) starts with:

```
export class MyApp {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http], [Platform], [IonicApp]];
  }

  constructor(http, platform, app) {

  }
}
```

this works ok.
But, let's say, I have a CustomService. How would I do to inject it to MyApp?

I tried with:

```
bootstrap(myApp, [SomeCustomService]);
```

but the console logs:
EXCEPTION: No provider for Http! (MyApp -> Http)

I'm I missing something? Did I understood worng some concepts?

Comment: Bro, to which file are you adding this line - bootstrap(myApp, [SomeCustomService]); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(myApp, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, SomeCustomService]);
```

Note that with Ionic2, there is no need to bootstrap your application. You can simply specify global providers on the class decorated with `@App`:

```
@App({
  (...)
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, SomeCustomService]
})
export class MyApp {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!